# Print line using egrep only

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

Print lines consisting of a definition of a single C variable of type int, without initialization, optionally preceded by unsigned, and optionally followed by any single line // comment.

I am using

```
egrep "^int.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*[^=].*;|^ unsigned int.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*[^=].*;" myfile.txt
```

It prints

```
int x=9;
int dftr2;
```

while it does not print

```
int x;
```

and it should not print

```
int x=9;
```

Here is the content of myfile.txt

```
int x;
int x=9;
int dftr2;
unsigned int dftrxe2;
unsigned int w=1;
```

The use of egrep is compulsory.

Comment: does it have to be a single `egrep` command or are pipes between multiple `egrep` executions allowed?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: your problem is this part `.*[^=].*;` because it requires the match to be at least 2 characters in length after `int` or `unsigned int`.  it also does not properly exclude `=` as you want because `.*` is doing something you do not expect/understand.

Answer (score 3):

If I take your question literally
(and don’t limit myself to trying to build on your incomplete answer)
I believe that the correct answer is:

```
egrep '^\s*(unsigned\s+)?int\s+[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\s*;\s*(//.*)?$' myfile.txt
```

Step by step:

- `^` to anchor the search to the beginning of the line.
- `\s*` to allow any number of whitespace characters (space or tab)
  to occur at the beginning of the line, before the declaration.
- `(unsigned\s+)?` to allow “unsigned” to appear zero or one time.

  - If it is present, it is followed by one *or more* spaces — `\s+`.
- `int\s+` matches the “int” keyword, also followed by one or more spaces.
- `[_A-Za-z]` — the first character of a C variable name
  must be a letter or an underscore (`_`).
- `[_A-Za-z0-9]*` — subsequent characters of a C variable name
  may be letters, underscores, *or digits*. 
  There may be any number of them (including zero,
  since we’re talking about what *follows* the first character).

  - (Some C compilers probably impose a maximum identifier length. 
    I don’t remember whether the Standard does,
    and I’m not going to bother looking it up.)
- `\s*` to allow any number of spaces …
- … before the `;`.
- `\s*` to allow any number of spaces *after* the semicolon.
- `(//.*)?` — optionally allow a `//` comment, and
- `$` to anchor the search to the end of the line.

If you want, you can

- replace `\s` with `[[:space:]]`
  or `[SpaceTab]`,

  - If you’re typing this at the keyboard,
    you may need to type <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>
    in order to get an actual tab character in the command line. 
    (Of course this won’t be an issue if you’re writing a script.)
- replace `[_A-Za-z]` with `[_[:alpha:]]`, and/or
- replace `[_A-Za-z0-9]*` with `[_[:alnum:]]`.

#### Counter-examples:

The

```
egrep '^(unsigned )?int [^=]*;' myfile.txt
```

command, shown in another answer, prints the following lines:

```
int a, b;               // Multiple variables declared.
int c; int d;           // Multiple “int” declarations.
int e; float f;         // Multiple declarations where only the first is an “int”.
int g[9];               // Array.
int *h;                 // Pointer.
int func();             // Function.
int 3D;                 // Illegal variable name.
int 42;                 // Not even an illegal variable name.
```

(which it should not print), and skips the following lines:

```
  int s;                // Space(s) at the beginning of the line.
int     t;              // Tab after “int”.
unsigned  int u;        // Multiple spaces after “unsigned”.
unsigned        int v;  // Tab after “unsigned”.
```

(which it should print).

Answer (score 1):

This looks for lines starting with `int` or `unsigned int` for which the statement terminates with `;` and does not contain `=`:

```
$ egrep '^(unsigned )?int [^=]*;' myfile.txt
int x;
int dftr2;
unsigned int dftrxe2;
```

Observe that this works with comments as well and correctly ignores any `=` in the comment.  Consider this test file:

```
$ cat myfile2.txt
int y; // y=height
int z=1; // z is depth
```

This is the result:

```
$ egrep '^(unsigned )?int [^=]*;' myfile2.txt
int y; // y=height
```

Lastly, note that `egrep` is deprecated.  `grep -E` is preferred:

```
grep -E '^(unsigned )?int [^=]*;' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `int` or `unsigned int` and then excluding anything found that include an `=` indicating something that is being initialized seems like it should do the job.

```
grep -E '^int|^unsigned int' myfile.txt | grep -Ev '='
```

Comment: Or `egrep '^(unsigned )?int'` to avoid typing both out.

Comment: (1) This command line is malformed, because the first `egrep` has an unspecified input, and the second one will read from the file and not the pipe. (2) But, even if we fix that, this rejects declarations that have a comment *when there’s an* `=` *in the comment.*

Comment: Well, I have corrected my answer per your objections.  It does address the OP's original examples, so I won't remove it for its "lacking correctness".